# Instantiating Java Class and then adding values to it

Tags: java, object, oop

So through LeetCode, I picked a question that asks to add 2 numbers from singly linked list. The following is the structure of LinkedList

```
public class ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode next;
     ListNode() {}
     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
}
```

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode head = newNode;
        while(l1 != null)
        {
            newNode((((l1.val)+(l2.val))%10));
            l1 = l1.next;
            l2 = l2.next;
            newNode = newNode.next;
            newNode = new ListNode();
        }
        newNode.next = null;
    return head;
    }
}
```

It gives an error saying "cannot find symbol newNode....."
Assuming both lists are the same size or length, I first instantiated ListNode class to newNode, and then within while loop, I am simply calling the same class since it has a constructor that takes 1 parameter and I pass the value from both list module 10.

Its been a while since I am doing Java, is this not allowed in Java? I know the solution but I just don't know why the above won't work?

Comment: `newNode((((l1.val)+(l2.val))%10))` I don't understand what you're trying to do with this line. `newNode` is a variable, not a method that you can call.

Comment: I am trying to add a value to newNode that is of type ListNode, and I pass an integer to the val variable(in the ListNode structure) through the constructor. Adding something to a class might look like this ListNode abc = new ListNode(20);    --->Notice integer 20 is passed. Now I want to do the same thing, except I first want to instantiate the class but pass the value later on

Comment: An object is only constructed once. You can't call a constructor of an existing instance. If you want to change the `val` member of `newNode`, you'll need to make a public setter method for that. Out of curiosity, is there a language that lets you re-call the constructor of an already-existing class instance?

Comment: Although, in this case, it would be better to keep ListNode immutable, and only ever create instances of it when you have values to initialize it with.

Comment: The solution to this problem that's given is a dummy object is constructed and then within while loop, they add the value by constructing a newer one (newNode.next = new ListNode(value);)  but I figured why create a useless Node. And @Tenfour04 I don't think there is. It actually makes sense not being able to call constructor after class is made. I guess I was thinking of JavaScript